# Spring Authorization Server doesn't run

Tags: spring-boot, spring-authorization-server

I am trying to setup spring authorization server using version 1.1.0-M2. But project doesn't run. In the previous version of spring authorization server runs well but logout doesn't work properly. Would you please help me by solving the issue. I have given the dependencies, configuration and the error in bellow:

My pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.futurezone</groupId>
    <artifactId>authorization-server</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <!--<packaging>war</packaging>-->
    <name>authorization-server</name>
    <description>authorization-server</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0-M2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>31.1-jre</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>20041127.091804</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-plugin</id>
            <name>Spring Plugins</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

Authorization Server Configuration class

```
import com.futurezone.authorizationserver.jose.Jwks;
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.JWKSet;
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.RSAKey;
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.source.JWKSource;
import com.nimbusds.jose.proc.SecurityContext;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.security.config.Customizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.oauth2.server.resource.OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.factory.PasswordEncoderFactories;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.AuthorizationGrantType;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.ClientAuthenticationMethod;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.oidc.OidcScopes;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.JdbcOAuth2AuthorizationConsentService;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.JdbcOAuth2AuthorizationService;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.OAuth2AuthorizationConsentService;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.OAuth2AuthorizationService;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.client.JdbcRegisteredClientRepository;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.client.RegisteredClient;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.client.RegisteredClientRepository;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.config.annotation.web.configuration.OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.config.annotation.web.configurers.OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.settings.AuthorizationServerSettings;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.settings.TokenSettings;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.UUID;


@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
public class AuthorizationServerConfig {

    @Bean
    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
    public SecurityFilterChain authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);
        http.getConfigurer(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.class)
                .oidc(Customizer.withDefaults());   // Enable OpenID Connect 1.0
        // @formatter:off
        http
                .exceptionHandling(exceptions ->
                        exceptions.authenticationEntryPoint(new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login"))
                )
                .oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt);
        // @formatter:on
        return http.build();
    }

    // @formatter:off
    @Bean
    public RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        PasswordEncoder encoder = PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
        // Save registered client in db as if in-memory
        JdbcRegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository = new JdbcRegisteredClientRepository(jdbcTemplate);
        RegisteredClient existingClient = registeredClientRepository.findByClientId("my-client");
        if(existingClient == null){
            RegisteredClient registeredClient = RegisteredClient.withId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                    .clientId("my-client")
                    .clientSecret(encoder.encode("123456"))
                    .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_BASIC)
                    .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
                    .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.REFRESH_TOKEN)
                    .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS)
                    .redirectUri("http://127.0.0.1:8080/login/oauth2/code/my-client-oidc")
                    .redirectUri("http://127.0.0.1:8080/authorized")
                    .postLogoutRedirectUri("http://127.0.0.1:8080/index")
                    .scope(OidcScopes.OPENID)
                    //.scope(OidcScopes.PROFILE)
                    .scope("read")
                    .scope("write")
                     .tokenSettings(TokenSettings.builder()
                            .accessTokenTimeToLive(Duration.ofDays(30))
                            .refreshTokenTimeToLive(Duration.ofDays(365))
                            .build())
                    //.clientSettings(ClientSettings.builder().requireAuthorizationConsent(true).build())
                    .build();
            registeredClientRepository.save(registeredClient);
        }
        return registeredClientRepository;
    }
    // @formatter:on

    
    @Bean
    public OAuth2AuthorizationService authorizationService(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate, RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository) {
        return new JdbcOAuth2AuthorizationService(jdbcTemplate, registeredClientRepository);
    }

    @Bean
    public OAuth2AuthorizationConsentService authorizationConsentService(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate, RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository) {
        return new JdbcOAuth2AuthorizationConsentService(jdbcTemplate, registeredClientRepository);
    }

    @Bean
    public JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource() {
        RSAKey rsaKey = Jwks.generateRsa();
        JWKSet jwkSet = new JWKSet(rsaKey);
        return (jwkSelector, securityContext) -> jwkSelector.select(jwkSet);
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder(JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource) {
        return OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.jwtDecoder(jwkSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthorizationServerSettings authorizationServerSettings() {
        return AuthorizationServerSettings.builder().build();
    }

    /*@Bean
    public EmbeddedDatabase embeddedDatabase() {
        // @formatter:off
        return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
                .generateUniqueName(true)
                .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
                .setScriptEncoding("UTF-8")
                .addScript("org/springframework/security/oauth2/server/authorization/oauth2-authorization-schema.sql")
                .addScript("org/springframework/security/oauth2/server/authorization/oauth2-authorization-consent-schema.sql")
                .addScript("org/springframework/security/oauth2/server/authorization/client/oauth2-registered-client-schema.sql")
                .build();
        // @formatter:on
    }*/
}
```

Security Configuration class

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
public class DefaultSecurityConfig {

    // @formatter:off
    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize ->
                        authorize.anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .formLogin(withDefaults());
        return http.build();
    }
    // @formatter:on


    @Bean
    SessionRegistry sessionRegistry() {
        return new SessionRegistryImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    HttpSessionEventPublisher httpSessionEventPublisher() {
        return new HttpSessionEventPublisher();
    }

}
```

Error

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-03-27T04:10:32.801+06:00 ERROR 7864 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [com/futurezone/authorizationserver/config/AuthorizationServerConfig.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain]: Factory method 'authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain' threw exception with message: org/springframework/security/oauth2/core/http/converter/OAuth2DeviceAuthorizationResponseHttpMessageConverter
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:652) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:640) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1161) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:561) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:961) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:915) ~[spring-context-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584) ~[spring-context-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:432) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1291) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at com.futurezone.authorizationserver.AuthorizationServerApplication.main(AuthorizationServerApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain]: Factory method 'authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain' threw exception with message: org/springframework/security/oauth2/core/http/converter/OAuth2DeviceAuthorizationResponseHttpMessageConverter
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:171) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:648) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/oauth2/core/http/converter/OAuth2DeviceAuthorizationResponseHttpMessageConverter
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2DeviceAuthorizationEndpointFilter.<init>(OAuth2DeviceAuthorizationEndpointFilter.java:79) ~[spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server-1.1.0-M2.jar:1.1.0-M2]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.config.annotation.web.configurers.OAuth2DeviceAuthorizationEndpointConfigurer.configure(OAuth2DeviceAuthorizationEndpointConfigurer.java:184) ~[spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server-1.1.0-M2.jar:1.1.0-M2]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.config.annotation.web.configurers.OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.lambda$configure$5(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.java:326) ~[spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server-1.1.0-M2.jar:1.1.0-M2]
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedValues.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:655) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.config.annotation.web.configurers.OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.configure(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.java:326) ~[spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server-1.1.0-M2.jar:1.1.0-M2]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.config.annotation.web.configurers.OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.configure(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.java:76) ~[spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server-1.1.0-M2.jar:1.1.0-M2]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.configure(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:349) ~[spring-security-config-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:303) ~[spring-security-config-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:38) ~[spring-security-config-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at com.futurezone.authorizationserver.config.AuthorizationServerConfig.authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain(AuthorizationServerConfig.java:58) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:139) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.http.converter.OAuth2DeviceAuthorizationResponseHttpMessageConverter
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ~[na:na]
    ... 36 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Could you upload it to github? Is this for a poc or enterprise? Are you open to other java iam?

Comment: Its solved. Used spring-security-oauth2-core version 6.1.0-M2 instead of spring-boot-starter-security. I will share github url for a sample project soon.

Comment: Awesome! It’s definitely an issue of using the spring boot provided spring security version instead of the latest milestone. I am unsure if the transitive dependency should be resolved over boot’s managed version or not though? It may be worth filing an issue so we can follow up in case there’s an issue with dependency management.

Comment: have you tried using version 1.0.2 of `spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server`?

Answer (score 3):

Please upgrade `Spring Security` to version `6.1.0`.

`OAuth2DeviceAuthorizationResponseHttpMessageConverter` class is present on `6.1.0+`, `Spring boot 3.0` is using `Spring Security 6.0.x`

Answer (score 3):

`spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server` version `1.1.0` requires/works only on `spring boot version 3.1.0` and above.

For `spring boot version 3.0` use `spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server` version `1.0.2`

Refer : https://github.com/m-thirumal/oauth-authorization-server

Answer (score 0):

I would first recommend you to define all your dependencies as show below

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
<groupId>com.futurezone</groupId>
    <artifactId>authorization-server</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <!--<packaging>war</packaging>-->
    <name>authorization-server</name>
    <description>authorization-server</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

The version tag in the parent tag shall set all the recommended versions in spring-boot-starter-data-jpa, spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server,spring-boot-starter-web,  spring-boot-starter-web, spring-boot-starter-test. I wouldn't recommend you to explicity define the version tag in a particular dependency (i.e., spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server)

```
    <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

The tag below allows you to inherit the version from the parent project and maintain consistency across multiple modules or projects

```
 <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change dependency from **spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server** to
**spring-boot-starter-oauth2-authorization-server** ,there is a lot of stuff autoconfigured with it.