# How to use spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server?

Tags: oauth-2.0

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kc6YF.png)
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.http.converter.OAuth2DeviceAuthorizationResponseHttpMessageConverter

I don't know to use it.

Where can I see the detailed usage documentation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Authorization Server doesn't run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75850924/spring-authorization-server-doesnt-run)